# Laravel 4 - JSON data and an Undefined Method

Tags: php, json, laravel-4

I am trying to select the last element from some JSON data but am getting an "Undefined Method" return. 
My code is to get the $order_serialized data from a specific Order and then to pick the $last_item in that JSON data and plug it into a dd() just for testing right now. If anyone could point out or explain where I went wrong it would be very much appreciated! Thank you so very much!

Controller:

```
public function getEdit($id){
    $order = Order::where('id', '=', $id);

    if($order->count()) {
        $order          = $order->first();
        $order_serialized   = json_decode($order->order_serialized);
        $last_item          = $order_serialized->last();


                    dd($last_item);


        foreach($order->order_serialized as $key => $value){
            $order->$key = $value;
        }
        return View::make('orders.edit')
                ->with('order', $order);
                /*->with('last_item', $last_item);*/
    }   else {
        return App::abort(404);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line are you getting the 'undefined method' error?

Comment: I am getting " undefined method stdClass::last() " on line 101.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

`$order_serialized   = json_decode($order->order_serialized);`

You get back a standard class object, so it doesn't have any `last()` method.

I would do this instead:

```
$order_serialized   = json_decode($order->order_serialized, true);
$last_item = array_pop($order_serialized);
```

Sending `true` as the second param to `json_decode` will give you an array instead of an object.

Answer (score 1):

`json_decode` is going to return a `stdClass` object which does not have any methods, so calling `$order_serialized->last()` is giving you the "undefined method" error. In order to call the `last` method on some class, you're going to have to instantiate that class. I don't know of a way to decode JSON to a specific class in PHP.

Comment: Thank you for explaining where I went wrong. Knowing what the problem is is a great place to start fixing it!